# Is it possible to post on the users wall with a developer or test account before getting approval from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-social-facebook

Is it possible to post on the users wall with a developer or test account before getting approval(review) from Facebook? It's supposed to work, but I'g getting "insufficient permissions" error when I try to update status using java spring social api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should by possible for admins/testers/developers of your app. The error message makes me suspicious that you probably didn't request the `publish_actions` permission upon Login to your app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed/#publish